# convert Julia expression to array?

Tags: julia

im getting a list that was saved as a string, and trying to parse it to use. I can use Meta.parse, to turn the string into an expression  :

```
li = db.list
print(typeof(d[1]),d[1])
>> String
   ["apple", "banana", "coconut"]

parsed_li = Meta.parse(d[1])
print(typeof(parsed_li), parsed_li)
>> Expr
   ["apple", "banana", "coconut"]
```

but it doesnt seem like i can use it like a normal list ; for example, with a normal list i could access an element by its index, but i cannot access the index of the Expr object :

```
normal_li = ["apple", "banana", "coconut"]
print(normal_li[1])
>> apple

print(parsed_li[1])
>>
MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Expr, ::Int64)

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at In[214]:8
```

i've been tinkering , not sure what I'm missing here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on `Meta.parse()` to parse your input data is both inefficient and unsafe (malicious code can be always inserted in the input data and you might be doing `eval` on it etc.). You rather instead use tools that are designed just for it. In your case just note that this data can be considered as a valid JSON format and can be read as follows:

```
julia> str = """["apple", "banana", "coconut"]"""
"[\"apple\", \"banana\", \"coconut\"]"

julia> using JSON3

julia> JSON3.read(str)
3-element JSON3.Array{String, Base.CodeUnits{UInt8, String}, Vector{UInt64}}:
 "apple"
 "banana"
 "coconut"

julia> collect(JSON3.read(str))
3-element Vector{String}:
 "apple"
 "banana"
 "coconut"
```

If you trust the input data (normally you never should) you can do it the unsafe way:

```
julia> eval(Meta.parse(str))
3-element Vector{String}:
 "apple"
 "banana"
 "coconut"
```

If you want to extract the information without `eval`, it could be done using `args` field of the `Expr` object - however the way it is handled will each time strongly depend on data structure:

```
julia> Meta.parse(str).args
3-element Vector{Any}:
 "apple"
 "banana"
 "coconut"
```

Comment: Good point about malicious input. A superficial check of the `Expr` head isn't even enough to guarantee `eval` safety. For example, `parsed_li.head` is `vect`, and one might think "well it's not a giant block of code or a method, it's just an Array". However, this is also an Array: `["apple", delete_all_your_files_and_steal_your_cat(), "coconut"]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's aways down in the [docs page](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Evaluating-expressions): `evaled_li = eval(parsed_li)` will be a Vector of String.

Answer (score 0):

`Expr` is not a list-like data structure.

Quoted from the [doc](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.Expr)

> `Expr`
>
> A type representing compound expressions in parsed julia code (ASTs).
> Each expression consists of a `head` `Symbol` identifying which kind of
> expression it is (e.g. a call, for loop, conditional statement, etc.),
> and subexpressions (e.g. the arguments of a call).
> The subexpressions are stored in a `Vector{Any}` field called `args`.

You can still access those elements through the `args` field though if you want.

Comment: yeah my question was if it can be converted to an array

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was clear that the `args` field is what you want in this specific case? Otherwise, I didn't see anything meaningful to convert a binary tree structure into a list here.

Comment: `parsed_li.args` is in fact a Vector of Any. An Expr has not been evaluated yet, so its `args` will hold Vectors of literals (String, Int, Float64), Symbol, or other Expr. Since your array only held Strings to begin with, this would actually suffice.